# i think an error appears to have occurred during "If"

Tags: python, numpy

```
from astropy.io import fits
from scipy.ndimage import gaussian_filter
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pdb

# Create empty image
nx, ny = 512, 512
image = np.zeros((ny, nx))

# Set number of stars
n = 10000

# Generate random positions
r = np.random.random(n) * nx
theta = np.random.uniform(0., 2. * np.pi, n)

# Generate random fluxes
f = np.random.random(n) ** 2

# Compute position
x = nx / 2 + r * np.cos(theta)
y = ny / 2 + r * np.sin(theta)

# Add stars to image
# ==> First for loop and if statement <==
for i in range(n):
    #pdb.set_trace()
    if x[i] >= 0 and x[i] < nx and y[i] >= 0 and y[i] < ny:
        #print(i)
        #pdb.set_trace()
        image[y[i], x[i]] += f[i]
        #print(i)

# Convolve with a gaussian
image = gaussian_filter(image, 1)

# Add noise
image += np.random.normal(3., 0.01, image.shape)

# Write out to FITS image
fits.writeto('cluster.fits', image, clobber=True)
```

it can be possible to occur an error between i=3 and i=4??
it comes out a message like this

> IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

is there anyone helping me?

Comment: You think? Did you run the code? What happened?

Comment: Post the exact error message. Apparently you're trying to index a list with something other than an integer.

Comment: You have `image[y[i], x[i]]` but `x` and `y` are arrays of floats, so you can't use them as array indexes.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put `y[i]` and `x[i]` as int:

```
image[int(y[i]),int(x[i])]
```

to be sure is not a float number.